# What kind of architecture is the best for communicating devices?

Tags: android, xml, design-patterns, architecture, xml-parsing

I'm developing two applications. The first one is a desktop `java` application and the second is an `Android` app.
This two apps must communicate among they.

Now, they communicates passing XML files and parsing then. The problem is that there is a lot of different XML and when I parse them I need to know what object y need to build.

For the moment I parse the root of the `XML` and depending the name I parse the remainder in a "switch" structure. It works but I think that is not the best way.

Somebody know a design pattern or an architecture defined already that can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm guessing correctly you are serializing/deserializing to/from XML in order for your applications to communicate, so on both ends of the channel you have objects.

If so, JAXB should cover your needs on the desktop side since, i don't know if it comes with android already or if you have a apk size limitation for your android app.

If you're already doing that, and your only problem is how to get rid of the "switch", in the end there is always some kind of choice, it may be a statement, or values in a configuration file, but in esscence that's the factory pattern for you, but i'd read some more into the [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), you already have the basics of it, perhaps it's just a matter of polishing it, or moving the values to a configuration file and automating  the creation process, which will require a common interface for objects i'm sure.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to rely on [XML namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) instead of a root element name. That's how you differentiate objects and make them validated, if necessary, with [XML Schemas](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema).

Besides that, I think that your protocol should be [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), with [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) in mind. XML is the best language for that kind of architecture.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but in the end I used abstract factory pattern. At any rate I want to thank your comment.

Comment: Upvote the answers you like most of all and select one of them as the best - this is how you say "thank you" at this site